# Accounting for Leap Years VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the following piece of code which starts the looking at year to date from Feb 1 instead of Jan 1. I have made the change, however It doesn't account for leap years. How can I modify this code to ensure that it accounts for the leap years. I am relatively new in VB. IS there a built in function that does?

```
Dim dt As Date
    Dim Y2Dday As Integer
    Dim Y2Dyear As Integer
    Dim strDepartment1 As String

    dt = dtpDate.Value
    'Y2Dday = -dt.DayOfYear + 32
    Y2Dday = -dt.DayOfYear + 366
    'If dt.DayOfYear > 31 Then
    If dt.DayOfYear > 365 Then
        Y2Dyear = 0
    Else
        Y2Dyear = -1
    End If
    strDepartment1 = strDepartment.Replace("departmentid", "o.departmentid")

    Dim collection As ItemCollection
    Dim qry As QueryItem

    collection = ItemCollection.GetInstance()
    qry = collection.GetQueryItem(intItem)
    If (Not qry Is Nothing) Then
        qry.SetQueryParameter(QueryItem.QueryParameter.DateFormat, intDateFormat.ToString())

        qry.SetQueryDate(1, dt.ToString)
        'Date used by Item(s) looking at Month to Date
        qry.SetQueryDate(2, dt.AddDays(-dt.Day + 1).ToString)

        'Date used by Item(s) looking at Year to Date
        qry.SetQueryDate(3, dt.AddDays(Y2Dday).AddYears(Y2Dyear).ToString)

        'Date used by Item(s) looking at Yesterday
        qry.SetQueryDate(4, dt.AddDays(-1).ToString)
```

Comment: If this worked for you, please click the checkmark

Answer (score 8):

the `DateTime` Type includes a `IsLeapYear(year as Integer)` function.  It is a Shared/Static function, so you invoke it using `DateTime` with a year value:

```
IsLeap = DateTime.IsLeapYear(myYearValue)
'  or
IsLeap = DateTime.IsLeapYear(myDt.Year)
```

or as an If:

```
If DateTime.IsLeapYear(myDate.Year) Then ...
```

It might seem confusing not being able to do `myDateVar.IsLeapYear`, but it allows you to test a year value without having to create a `DateTime` variable first.